# Not able to include widgets in a Toplevel container in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code using `Tkinter` that opens one window, then (after clicking a button) opens a `Toplevel` container. I'm trying to put an `Label` widget into this additional window, but keep getting an error saying "can't invoke label command: application has been destroyed."

How can I keep my `root.Tk()` window open to avoid this error?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("First Window")


NewWin = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=newwin)
NewWin.pack()


def newwin():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.wm_title("Second Window")

Praise = Label(top, text="Good Work!")
Praise.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Up until the label I try to install in the second window, the code works. How can I keep both windows up and running?

Comment: It seems impossible for the code you posted to give the error you say it does (I am not at a computer where I can check). Part of the problem is that you are using `top` before it is defined, since it is defined as a local variable in a function that hasn't been called yet.

Comment: @Bryan I saw the same thing. This code needed quite a bit of rearrangement.

Comment: What if instead I define `top` before I implement it in the command `newwin` and just use `.destroy` to keep it hidden? I'll try that

Comment: If you `destroy()` it you can't do anything with it, so that's not the right way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I tried and it didn't work. How else can I keep the window hidden other than `.destroy()`?

Comment: That would be `withdraw()`, but it's also not what you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that local variables are not visible to wider scopes. Therefore, the `top` reference does not exist as far as the rest of the program is concerned. The easiest option is to put all of that window's logic into the function that creates it.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("First Window")

def new_win():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.wm_title("Second Window")
    praise = Label(top, text="Good Work!")
    praise.grid()

new_win_button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=new_win)
new_win_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You could also go to an OO approach and simply save references to all relevant objects within the application:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.wm_title("First Window")
        self.new_win_button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=self.new_win)
        self.new_win_button.pack()
        self.populate_button = Button(root, text="Populate", command=self.populate)
        self.populate_button.pack()
    def new_win(self):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.wm_title("Second Window")
    def populate(self):
        self.praise = Label(self.top, text="Good Work!")
        self.praise.grid()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I've also cleaned up your variable names so that they don't look like class names (e.g. `MyClass` vs. `my_label`).

Comment: And if the OP does want populate as a separate function, then a test to see if top exists should be added.  They would add "self.top=None" to "__init__" and "if self.top:" to populate()  I wish there was a way to let beginners know that Tkinter is much simpler with classes.